# How to consume the subscription type in app product purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription, product

I have implemented the subscription type in-app products in my app like 1 month or 2 months package, once a user subscribe to the product I let the server know and deal with him/her accordingly and it is working very fine.

According to Google at completion of subscription period:

> Google auto-cut the credit and renew the package.

**My problem:** How do I get to know the user who have paid for next the month or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of active purchases from Google Play, and then update your server accordingly (e.g. daily).

```
IInAppBillingService service = ...;
Bundle items = service.getPurchases(API_VERSION, PACKAGE_NAME, "subs", null);
int response = getResponseCodeFromBundle(items);
if (response != RESULT_OK) {
  // handle error
}
ArrayList<String> productIDs = items.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
// update server with active product ids
```

Comment: If subscription is expired, it gets out of list?

Comment: returns an history of subscriptions or just an active subscription?

Answer (score 7):

Answering the question: You cant consume the subscriptions. You can consume only inapps.

Quote from docs:

`Important: Unlike in-app products, subscriptions cannot be consumed.`
Source: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

That page leads to these two: 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Subs

Also notice that when offering subscription, it is best to allow user to restore the subscription. For example if a user logged in in your app, purchased a subscription and then logged in with another username, the subscription should be available there too, because it is attached to users google play account.

To do that you should query for purchased subs like **marmor** specified.

Comment: Why subscription has to be available if user log in with other account? If my app is connected to a server and I validate subscription with it, it's not logical that subscription is attached to current gmail account instead of my app user account. It doesn't really matter if subscriptions are attached to users google play account: if user try to log in with another account into my app, the subscription must be different because he/she is a different user.

Comment: Its in the guidelines of Google Play.

Comment: -1 because in my opinion this is wrong. The account is bundled with Google Play. If you have another account, then you have another Google Play instance too. These are completely different users that don't have to have anything in common. I doubt there is a guideline which tells me that I have to share Subscriptions with different (or even unknown) users. But maybe you could show us this part of the guideline?

Comment: The account meant the account in the app, not in Google Play. Please read carefully before downvoting.

Comment: Is there at least some Intent to reach a place to cancel subscriptions, then?